# Access Rights Browser Tool - Bigquery Export

Tags: google-bigquery

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or the feature I am looking for is not supported.

I have users who have access as "Can View" for the project. All our data exist in dataset-A. I have created a new dataset (dataset-B) in same project and explicitly given them access to create table.

However, for some reason they still don't have permission to export the result of their query to the new dataset.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing should work. As long as the user is on the dataset with at least write permissions they should be able to create tables in that dataset.

Can you give the name of the dataset, the project, and the user for whom you are trying to add permissions? Can you also describe how the user is trying to create the table?

Comment: Here is what I have found: The user has "Can View" permission on dataset-A. When they run a query and try to do "Save As Table". They get "Access Denied: ....:RUN_JOB". We don't want to give access as "Owner" to run the job. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Our ACL model disallows this. I'm in the process of discussing with the rest of the team whether we can allow it... it makes sense to me that this should work, but we had originally set it up so that you needed writer/editor access on the project to run a job in the project.

Comment: We tried Edit as well and it does not allow. Only way it allows is to be "Owner". The problem giving access as Edit/Owner is someone can accidentally delete the tables. I feel that this is important feature to make it useful. Let me know what you decide.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that Editor should have worked. It is possible the editor group membership was cached somewhere. I've just checked in a change that allows project Viewers/Readers to be able to run jobs in the project. This should go out in our next release, likely midweek next week.

Comment: Please let me know if this was released.

Comment: Yes, this was released Wednesday afternoon. Let me know if you still encounter problems.

Comment: Looks like it is now broken for "Can View" User. They are able to create temp tables on the dataset-A they don't have permission and delete the existing table.

Comment: Deleting a table requires write access on the dataset. Are you saying you want read access to allow deleting tables?

Comment: No. I am saying that the functionality is broken as of last change. We are seeing that user with "Can View" permission is able to delete the tables on the dataset where they don't have any permissions.